# Missing translation for QgsMessageBar in standalone PyQGIS app

Tags: pyqgis, standalone, internationalization

I am running a standalone PyQGIS application. Using `QgsMessageBar` I noticed that it is not using the local translation.

Consider this minimal example running in a OSGeo4W environment (using all the right environment variables) on a German Windows machine. Ignore how broken it might be in terms of Qt structure, I stripped it down as much as possible to have a minimal example that shows the issue.

```
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, Qgis
from qgis.gui import QgsMessageBar

app = QgsApplication([], True)
app.initQgis()

print(app.locale())
# "de" = correct

print(app.i18nPath())
# "C:/Users/user/path/apps/qgis-ltr/./i18n/"
# "C:\Users\user\path\apps\qgis-ltr\i18n\" contains "qgis_de.qm"
# seems correct

message_bar = QgsMessageBar()
message_bar.pushMessage("Locale", f"{app.locale()}", level=Qgis.Critical)
# Bug: Mouseover on the X icon of the message says "Close", not the german "Schließen"

app.exec()
```

This results in a tiny window like this:

[image]

If I run the QGIS of that environment normally, the GUI is in German and a `QgsMessageBar`'s close button does say "Schließen".

As you can see in the code above, I checked the locale and path to the translation file(s) and it all seems correct.

How do I get the available translation to work in my standalone application?

Comment: What this gives you `QSettings().value('locale/userLocale', QLocale().name())` ?

Comment: That gives me `de_DE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up and install a [`QTranslator`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtranslator.html):

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QTranslator

translator = QTranslator(app)
translator.load(f"{app.i18nPath()}qgis_{app.locale()}.qm")
app.installTranslator(translator)
```

This will fail silently if the specified translation file could not be loaded.